# ola hallengren Index Maintenance script - GUID Index

Tags: index, ola-hallengren, uuid

We been running ola hallengren Index Maintenance script and was ran into a problem with some indexes that have GUID as the Index Key, They are Frag and have a page count of 6,309, but they don’t get scanned to be rebuild or reorg.

Has anyone heard of this or know of a fix for this?

```
/****** Object:  Index [idx_GUID]    Script Date: 01/14/2015 10:54:47 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_GUID] ON [dbo].[ckbx_InvitationRecipients] 
(
      [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: How fragmented are the GUID indexes?  If less than 5% (or the value you configured) they will not defrag. If you look in Ola's "Frequently Asked Questions" it may help.

Comment: Indexes are Over 80%

Comment: Problem Solved, was running standard.  Had to use "offline"